# System.IO.Compression DLL Missing and Possible Version Conflict

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm building an ASPNET Core/EF Core/MVC 6 website which will ultimately run under Azure. I'm running into an odd problem involving a dependency DLL which I've never encountered before.

The solution consists of a number of projects. Several of those manipulate zip files via ZipArchive, so they have a dependency on System.IO.Compression. The solution compiles without a problem.

However, the System.IO.Compression DLL wasn't copied to the final bin directory, which naturally caused the site to crash when it tried to access the routines in that assembly.

I "solved" that problem by manually copying System.IO.Compression.dll to the final bin directory. The site runs fine on my development system.

But when I publish the site to Azure, System.IO.Compression.dll doesn't get deployed, and the Azure site crashes when trying to access the missing assembly.

I'm not sure if I can manually copy the missing DLL to Azure, but if I can I suppose that's one solution.

But this all feels kludgy, and like I'm missing something.

So I went back and looked through the references in each of the projects, and noticed something odd.

In a "subsidiary" project -- ConnellData -- displaying the references shows, as expected, a dependency on System.IO.Compression, v4.1.0.

But when I look in the "main" project, which depends on ConnellData, and expand the references for ConnellData...there's a dependency on System.IO.Compression, but it's for version 4.0.10.

I don't know if this is related to the missing DLL problem, but it seems like it might.

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to fix this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: As I know, if you find the dll missing and upload it to Azure. It will help to fix the issue. However the important thing is to fix the dll conflict.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being easy to solve...but hard to diagnose.

My project.json file had the following frameworks entry:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
    }
  },
```

It also stated a dependency, under the dependency section, for System.IO.Compression.

Unfortunately, that's a >>different<< System.IO.Compression, part of Net Core. What I was using as the built-in net46 assembly System.IO.Compression.

To include that in a project, you have to add it to the frameworkAssemblies section, not the dependency section:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.IO.Compression": "4.0.0.0"
      },
    }
  },
```

Doing this is each of the projects in my solution which were relying on the net46 version of System.IO.Compression -- and deleting the System.IO.Compression entry from the dependencies section -- solved the problem.